# How to get latest post id in functions.php Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function, posts

Can anyone help me to get latest post id in Wordpress functions.php file.
I think it must be something like

```
global $wp_query;
$thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

But cant figure out what next.

Thanks

Comment: you want to get id of first post?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`wp_get_recent_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts):

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) );
$thePostID = $recent_posts[0]['ID'];
```

Comment: Looks like it dont work. I got error:  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 1577

Comment: Increasing memory allocated to PHP: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP